# CakePHP 2.0: How to redirect a url like /details.php?id=1234 to /articles/show/1234?

Tags: .htaccess, url, cakephp, redirect

I already checked this: [CakePHP and .htaccess: how to redirect url with query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006825/cakephp-and-htaccess-how-to-redirect-url-with-query-string) but it's not working for me.

I have these kind of url's in Google: /details.php?id=1234 and want this to redirect to the url /details/1234

Is there a way to use cakes redirect: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing ?

Or do I need to do this in the htaccess? If yes, in which one? The /root/htaccess or the /root/webroot/htaccess?

Please advice!
Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation in my application that I am handling in the following manner:

Basically, I was using a system of URLs that is different than now. Bookmarks are on Facebook and all over the web.... Anyway, people were accessing my page like this

```
http://www.domain.com/?c=123&a=2261
```

c=123 refered to the category in which the article belonged to and a=2261 was in reference to the article id that was migrated to my new site. Now my url was like the following:

```
http://www.domain.com/article/slug-for-the-article-in-question
```

I used the following code in my `app_controller.php`

```
function CheckOldUrl(){
    preg_match("/a=(\\d{1,})/ui", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
    if(!$matches == NULL){
        $this->redirect('/articles/articleRedirect/'.$matches[1]);
    }
}
```

Then I setup a function in my articles controller (articleRedirect) to check the right article in DB, get its slug and redirect to the correct new article url.

```
function articleRedirect($article_id = NULL){
        $this->Article->recursive = -1;
        $slug = $this->Article->findById($article_id);        
        if($slug == NULL){
            $this->Session->setFlash('This article does not exist!','default',array('class'=>'alert_error'));
            $this->redirect('/articles');
        }else{
            $this->redirect('/article/'.$slug['Article']['slug']);
        }
}
```

---

---

### **Anyway, for you I would suggest the following, although I have not tested it....**

```
function beforeFilter(){
    ...
    $this->CheckOldUrl();
    ...
}

function CheckOldUrl(){
    preg_match("/id=(\\d{1,})/ui", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
    if(!$matches == NULL){
        $this->redirect('/articles/show/'.$matches[1]);
    }
}
```